# Accessing the Address Book in iOS Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, device

Presently I'm developing an app which will make use of the contacts available in the Address book of  the device.

I want to get the list of contacts via. the address book, with option of checkboxes besides each of the contact. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: closevote: Please do not take it as offensive, you seem to be a new user so I just want to explain "why". This site is not meant for "guide me", "write me a tutorial", "teach me" and similar questions. This kind are not regarded as "questions" here. There are different sites and interest groups dedicated to teaching/guiding. SO is meant to help with concrete problems, not vagues like "I dont know how to start".

Answer (score 4):

Look into `ABAddressBook` framework . Get the list of contacts as an array and populate this list in a UItableview and you can use `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` for showing selected contacts.

See the code below. It returns an array containing contacts. Here AddressObject is a modal class.

```
-(NSArray*)addressBookLoader
{
    CFErrorRef *error = NULL;

    NSMutableArray *arrayofAddressClassObjects =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,error);

    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef sortedPeople =ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);

    //RETRIEVING THE FIRST NAME AND PHONE NUMBER FROM THE ADDRESS BOOK

    CFIndex number = CFArrayGetCount(sortedPeople);

    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *phoneNumber ;

    for( int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {

        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sortedPeople, i);
        firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0);

        if(phoneNumber != NULL)
        {

            AddressObject *obj = [[AddressObject alloc]init];
            obj.contactName = firstName;
            obj.contactNumber = phoneNumber;

            [arrayofAddressClassObjects addObject:obj];

        }


    }

    NSLog(@"x=%@",arrayofAddressClassObjects);

    return arrayofAddressClassObjects;

}
```

Comment: Hi @Xcoder need the modal class for reference...

Answer (score 2):

To access the address book, look into using [ABAddressBook.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)

> The ABAddressBook opaque type (whose instances are known as address
>   books) provides a programming interface to the Address Book—a
>   centralized database used by multiple applications to store personal
>   information about people. The Address Book database also supports the
>   notion of a “group” containing one or more persons. People may belong
>   to multiple groups, and groups may also belong to other groups.
>
> The ABAddressBook opaque type provides functions for creating
>   references to the Address Book database, saving changes, discarding
>   changes, and registering for changes made externally (by other threads
>   or processes) to the database.

Populate a `UITableView` with the results of your address book and then add a checkmark to each UITableViewCell programmatically, something like the following:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```